# Call Jasper report from external application through URL

Tags: json, web-services, jasper-reports, jasperserver

My requirement is,
I have a url in my windows application that is pointing to a jasper report in the jasper server
I only need my jasper server as a query builder,
when I call the Report from my application(which has the result) the result should come as a JSON data using web service.
How can I achieve it.
Is it possible?
correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.place the fields in the detail band and add the property    "net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" in each field 
2.deploy on server so it will available for the rest_v2 calls

Answer (score 1):

For **raw data** in `XML` or `JSON` you can use **JasperServer Domains and the REST Query Executor service**

You need JasperReports Server v5.1 or later and an edition with **Metadata Layer**, commercial!

[The v2/queryExecutor Service](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v550/v2queryexecutor-service)

[REST endpoint for Jaspersoft Query Executor](https://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/rest-endpoint-for-jaspersoft-query-executor/)

**Summary** (only useful if link get broken)

Call:

```
{scheme}://{host}:{port}/{contextPath}/rest_v2/queryExecutor/{resourceUri}?q={queryString}
```

`{queryString}` need to be in this format and url encoded (reefer to [JasperReports Server User Guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-user-guide_1.pdf) for more detail

```
<query>
  <queryFields>
    <queryField id="inv_store.inv_store__store_name" />
    <queryField id="inv_store.inv_store__store_type" />
    <queryField id="inv_store__store_contact.inv_store__store_contact__store_manager" />
  </queryFields>
  <queryFilterString>inv_store__region.inv_store__region__sales_state_province == 'CA'</queryFilterString>
</query>
```

Example

```
http://localhost/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/queryExecutor/public/Samples/Domains/supermartDomain?q=%3Cquery%3E%3CqueryFields%3E%3CqueryField+id%3D%22inv_store.inv_store__store_name%22+%2F%3E%3CqueryField+id%3D%22inv_store.inv_store__store_type%22+%2F%3E%3CqueryField+id%3D%22inv_store__store_contact.inv_store__store_contact__store_manager%22+%2F%3E%3C%2FqueryFields%3E%3CqueryFilterString%3Einv_store__region.inv_store__region__sales_state_province+%3D%3D+'CA'%3C%2FqueryFilterString%3E%3C%2Fquery%3E
```

This will return result in `xml`, to get `json` format add the header `“Accept: application/json”` to your request.

For authentication before call refer to the [JasperReports Server Web Service Guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide_1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, It helps me Petter. What IF I have a jasper report ready with query in the jasper server and only need a call to that report and get JSON data as out put?(I need this json data as a data feeder to other application) How to add the JSON exporter property in jasper server 6.1.And sample steps to follow

Comment: It is working. what I did is ,I place the fields in the detail band and add the property "net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" in each field and deployed on server so it is available for the rest_v2 json responses .Thanks